# Contador de soluções em recursão

Tags: python, variáveis, recursão, variáveis-globais

Olá, fiz um programa Sudoku recursivo, está funcionando bem, porém gostaria de adicionar um contador de soluções, testei inúmeras alterações no código que possibilitassem isso, mas não funcionou, por fim tentei uma solução usando variáveis globais como implementaria em C como último recurso, e também não funcionou, mas não sei se usei essa variável corretamente, o código em python me retornou o seguinte erro:

```
File "~/CCR/UserFiles/Marcilio/Sudoku/sudoku.py", line 176, in Sudoku
    contador += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'contador' referenced before assignment
```

segue o código, com a variável global, ou se houver outra forma pra resolver e puderem me sugerir agradeço:

```
contador = 0

def Sudoku(Mat, lin, col):   
    lin, col = ProcuraCasas(Mat)    
    if lin == -1 and col == -1:
        if TestaMatrizPreenchida(Mat):
            contador += 1
            ImprimaMatriz(Mat)
            print("\t")
        else: print("Preenchimento incorreto")    
    else:
        for candidato in range (1, 10):
            if VerificaCandidato (Mat, lin, col, candidato) is True:
                Mat[lin][col] = candidato     
                Sudoku(Mat, lin, col)           
        Mat[lin][col] = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No inicio da sua função adicione: `global contador`